# send data from screen to Tab screen using react-native-router-flux

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-router-flux

I am trying to send the data from one screen to another using react-native-router-flux, But the problem is that i am unable to receive data at the receiving end of the screen. Here is my code snippet:

In router.js

```
<Router>
    <Stack key="root">
      <Scene
        key="signup"
        component={Signup}
        title=""
        initial={true}
        hideNavBar={true}
      />
      <Scene key="login" component={Login} title="" />

      <Scene key="bottomtourbar" tabs={true} hideNavBar={true}>
        <Scene
          key="toursHome"
          component={Tours}
          title="Tours"
          hideTabBar={true}
          hideNavBar={false}
        />
        <Scene
          key="analytics"
          component={Analytics}
          title="Analytics"
          hideNavBar={true}
          hideNavBar={false}
        />
       </Scene>
      </Stack>
  </Router>
```

In Login.js im an using the below code to pass parameter to toursHome page

```
Actions.toursHome({dataResponse:jsonResponse});
```

In ToursHome.js file I am trying to access the parameter sent by login page

```
export default class Tours extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  };
  render() {
    const responseData = this.props.dataResponse;
    console.log(responseData);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ToursTab />
        <View style={styles.TabbedContainer}>
          <Text>{responseData}</Text>
        </View>

        <ToursBottom />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

In console it prints as undefined.

Sending props from sign-up screen to login works by using "Actions.login({dataResponse:jsonResponse});", But sending props from login to tab bar screen fails .
Can anyone help me get through this issue.

Comment: "jsonResponse" is having some data or your were trying to add simple string??

Comment: jsonResponse consists json Array, I have printed jsonResponse before sending it , and it shows the data is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried achieving that in many different ways. But I learned "the hard way" that passing props through `Actions` to scenes on different levels (depth, as in your case `toursHome` scene is nested under `bottomtourbar` scene) is only properly done through redux. If your scenes are connected to redux (using connect()) then update the state in the store and it should be available to your connected component through `mapStateToProps`.

Otherwise, passing props between scenes using `Actions` is doable for scenes on the same level/depth (for example in your case it is going to successfully pass the props with `Actions` between `analytics` and `toursHome` or `signup` and `login`)

Comment: Thanks for the reply , couldn't find any other way so storing data with AsyncStorage to get data.

Comment: can you give the snippet